# Why would a maxed out TCP buffer allow some HTTP and not others

Tags: tcp

I recently had an issue where my network lost the majority of its HTTP connectivity. I couldn't access a single HTTP based site.

I could ping addresses across the internet, messaging apps like whatsapp were functioning and other none HTTP apps were also functioning. Access to google (and its subsidiaries like YouTube and Gmail), and Facebook were also unaffected.

At first I thought it was a DNS issue but ruled this out with nslookup. Then I thought it was our firewall, but when bypassing all LAN devices and directly connecting to our modem the issue persisted. At this point I wanted to check with the ISP whether it was an issue upstream.

Tech support then told me that they had experienced this problem before and it was actually an issue with the TCP buffer on our modem. They told me the buffer max level was set too high and too many sessions had maxed it out. They reduced the buffer size and after a reboot, connectivity was back to normal.

What I dont understand is why I was able to access some websites that used HTTPS but not others, and none that used HTTP. Surely a maxed out buffer would impact on all TCP based traffic?

The problem is solved now but, for my own understanding, I want to know why the solution worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: I wouldn't call an iDirect x7 consumer grade but there you go.

Comment: The network is a professional network of around 150 end user devices which I manage. It is my first administrative position therefore I apologise if my questions seem basic but I have a lot to learn.

Comment: The modem supplied and controlled by your ISP is the device to which I am referring. If you don't control it, it is off-topic here. You will need to ask your ISP about the problem and solution. Protocols above OSI layer-4, including HTTP and HTTPS, are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

that's just a pseudo-science answer from support meant to make you feel good.

The modem likely has a bug, perhaps doing connection tracking for port 80, and leaked a bunch of resources over time. The reboot cleared it up.

Comment: I had tried a number of reboots both soft and hard and the issue didnt clear. 

I also noticed a huge spike in TCP sessions around the time of the outage: 1400M when our standard is 4-500.